# How to test Parent passing `this` to Children using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have below code where `Parent` Component is passing it's `this` to `Child` Component. `Child` Component will do some work and then do `setState` in `Parent` Component.

How Should i go about testing only Child Component. Means how can i create dummy `Parent` and later on check value in it's state using `enzyme` & `jest`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            status: '',
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Child 
                    parentThis={this}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

    doSomeWork = () => {
        const {parentThis} = this.props;
        parentThis.setState({
            'status': '1'
        })
    }

    render() {
        this.doSomeWork()
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}
```

I want to do Unit testing of `Child` Component. I want to make sure that `Child` is correctly updating `state` of `Parent` Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

> I have below code where Parent Component is passing it's this to Child
>   Component. Child Component will do some work and then do setState in
>   Parent Component.

Don't do that. That is never a good pattern for testing purposes - and neither a good pattern in React.

React allows you to pass functions to components, in your case a callback. So instead of passing `this`, pass a function `onChangeStatus`. A full example might look like the following:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            status: '',
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onChangeStatus={(status) => this.setState({status})}
                       status={this.state.status}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

    doSomeWork = () => {
        const {onChangeStatus} = this.props;
        onChangeStatus({
            status: '1'
        })
    }

    render() {
        this.doSomeWork()
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}
```

To test it, just test if a function you pass to the child gets called. I seldom use enzyme, but [this article](https://bambielli.com/til/2018-03-04-directly-test-react-component-methods/) looks promising on how to test the function.